# How can I add sliders to this plot function?

Tags: plot, julia, makie.jl

I have a function that creates a plot with sliders. The code is based on the first example from [this Makie tutorial](https://makie.juliaplots.org/stable/examples/layoutables/slider/index.html#slider)

```
function plotLaneEmden(log_delta_xi=-4, n=3)    

    fig = Figure()

    ax = Axis(fig[1, 1])
 
    sl_x = Slider(fig[2, 1], range = 0:0.01:4.99, startvalue = 3)
    sl_y = Slider(fig[1, 2], range = -6:0.01:0.1, horizontal = false, startvalue = -2)

    point = lift(sl_x.value, sl_y.value) do n, log_delta_xi
        Point2f(n, log_delta_xi)
    end

    plot(n,  1 .- log_delta_xi.^2/6,  linecolor = :green, label="n = $n")
    
    xlabel!("ξ")
    ylabel!("θ")

end
```

I get the errors and the warning messages:

```
WARNING: both GLMakie and Plots export "ylabel!"; uses of it in module Main must be qualified
WARNING: both GLMakie and Plots export "xlabel!"; uses of it in module Main must be qualified
WARNING: both GLMakie and Plots export "plot"; uses of it in module Main must be qualified
UndefVarError: plot not defined
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have in your code:

```
using GLMakie 
using Plots
```

This causes both modules to export `plot` command.
In that case you need to write:

```
GLMakie.plot(....)
GLMakie.xlabel!("ξ")
```

You could also consider doing:

```
using GLMakie 
import Plots
```

In that case you will not have the naming clash for both libraries. You can still use then any method from `Plots` by typing `Plots.methodname(.....)`

Comment: Thanks for this. However, after revising the methods, I am still not able to get sliders on my plot.